# DataGridView Column sorting depending on other column value

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am using DataGridView and have two columns "Index" and "Sub-Index".
When I click on Ascending sort for "Index" column. I want "Sub-Index" column to automatically get sorted to ascending depending on "Index" column data.

*Before Sort*:

**Index**        **Sub-Index**
3             2
3             1
2             3
1             3
2             2
1             2

*After Sort*:

**Index**        **Sub-Index**
1             2
1             3
2             2
2             3
3             1
3             2

I am not going to allow sorting on "Sub-index" column.
Whenever I click on sorting "Index" column , the "Sub-index" column should be sorted depending on the "Index" column value.

My DataGridView is not bound to any DataTable. I manually populate dataGridview by adding rows and columns.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort on multicolumns on the defaultview. Put this code in your columnheader click event.

```
  private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Index")
        {
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.Sort = "Index, Subindex";
        }
    }
```

This does assume you are bound to a `DataTable` though

Comment: Thanks Dan ! But my DataGridView is not bound to DataTable. Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: I'm not sure, have you tried the link posted by @Yasser Zamani? Otherwise you could add your data to a DataTable instead of directly to the gridview and then bind to the datatable and use my solution above. I think this will be the simplest solution for you. Adding data to a table instead of the gridview is much of a muchness but this will allow you to sort the view which can sort by multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort this out like [DataGridView Multi-column Sort](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18440/DataGridView-Multi-column-Sort)